# Extract the number of invoices of the current year in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by

Goodmorning everyone.
I'm going crazy
I need to extract the number of invoices from the current year per customer.
in my table **tbl_preventivi** I have the field **anagrafica_id** for the customer and **date_prev** for the date of the invoice.
this is my code.

```
$anno = date('Y');    
SELECT tbl_preventivi.anagrafica_id, Count(tbl_preventivi.preventivo_id) AS totale
    FROM tbl_preventivi
    GROUP BY tbl_preventivi.anagrafica_id, Year(tbl_preventivi.data_prev)
    HAVING ((Year(tbl_preventivi.data_prev) = ".$anno.") AND (tbl_preventivi.anagrafica_id=".$_GET['anagrafica_id']."))
```

i am sure that in the test i am doing the result must be 1, instead the query is null.
if I remove
`(Year(tbl_preventivi.data_prev) = ".$anno.") AND`  the query works and returns 6 (which is the number of invoices made even in previous years).
where am i wrong?

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: Welcome to SO. For the preservation of your sanity, and ours, please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be something like:

```
SELECT p.`anagrafica_id`,
       COUNT(p.`preventivo_id`) as `totale`
  FROM `tbl_preventivi` p
 WHERE p.`anagrafica_id` = 12345 and YEAR(p.`data_prev`) = 9999
 GROUP BY p.`anagrafica_id`;
```

> **Note:** `12345` should be replaced with a sanitized customer number, and `9999` should be replaced with a sanitized and logical year. Prepared statements are your friend here.

If you wish to see *all* invoices for a customer across all years, you can do this:

```
SELECT p.`anagrafica_id`,
       YEAR(p.`data_prev`) as `year`,
       COUNT(p.`preventivo_id`) as `totale`
  FROM `tbl_preventivi` p
 WHERE p.`anagrafica_id` = 12345
 GROUP BY p.`anagrafica_id`, `year`
 ORDER BY `year` DESC;
```

Again, be sure to sanitize your inputs. In the famous words of Fox Mulder: *Trust no one.*

Comment: thank you very much
i'm learning some php on my own ...
you gave me a great hand (especially to sanitize my inputs)